# How do I use keyboard shortcuts to enter a value into a cell that has a list data validation entry?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2016

So I used data validation to only allow an user to enter values from a list. How do I select something from the list without using the mouse?

For example, here's what I made:

[image]

Clicking on the little arrow beside the active cell will give me a drop-down using which I can select an appropriate value. How do I do this with just my keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Navigate to the cell

2) Press `<ALT><Arrow down>`

3) Navigate to the menu entry with the up/down arrows

4) Press `<Enter>` to accept the selected entry

Comment: note also that the tab key will often move from location to location to facilitate non-mouse navigation.